# Angularjs email validation without required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Title tells the problem shortly, I have a few email fields like so:

```
Email 1: <input type="email" name="email1" ng-model="emails.email1" />
<br />
Email 2: <input type="email" name="email2" ng-model="emails.email2" />
```

I am using following css to see the result:

```
input[type="email"].ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
    background-color: #FA787E;
  }
```

The problem is, validation doesn't fire unless I add required attribute. Inputs take classes "`ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty`" when I input `abc`.

I don't want to put required attribute because I want them to be optional and be validated only if a user wants to fill an e-mail address. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide a Fiddle.

Comment: Somebody downvotes us all but doesn't have time to leave a comment? (Not to you blackhole, I'm trying to prepare a fiddle)

Comment: It works with fiddle, I couldn't find what breaks it in actual code yet. Thanks @Blackhole for checking.

Comment: Shouldn't this be deleted?

Comment: It says that I shouldn't delete the question because it has answers when I try to delete it.

Answer (score -1):

In Angular 1.3 this is better supported. See the following page for details:
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html#html5-validators-and-parse-errors

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to leverage the native angular validation methods:

For example with a form name of "form"

```
form.email1.$error.emails.email1
form.email2.$error.emails.email2
```

And the data methods:

```
{{!!form.$error.emails.email1}}
{{!!form.$error.emails.email2}}
```

From there, just mark the fields dirty and your styling should be applied.

[Read more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D)